# Java software design

Tags: java

### Scenario:

Consider the following abstract class `MeasurementType` and its subtypes `Acceleration` and `Density`:

```
public abstract class MeasurementType {
  protected String name;
  protected String[] units;

  public MeasurementType() {}

  public MeasurementType(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  protected void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  protected String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  protected void setUnits(String[] values) {
    this.units = values;
  }
}

public class Acceleration extends MeasurementType {
  private String name;

  public Acceleration () {
    super();
  }

  public Acceleration(String name) {
    super();
  }

}

public class Density extends MeasurementType {
  private String name;

  public Density() {
    super();
  }

  public Density(String name) {
    super();
  }

}
```

### Question:

What is the need for the subtypes are since there isn't anything in those classes that differentiates them apart enough (at least in my implementations) to give them the right to exist as their own entities, but for the sake of the example, lets say they had their own arrays containing units for each distinct type, so density would have kilograms, grams etc.. and acceleration would have mph, kmph etc..

Finally I have this run class which I quickly made up:

```
public class run {

  public run() {}

  public static MeasurementType testType() {
    Acceleration a = new Acceleration("meters per second");
    return (MeasurementType) a;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MeasurementType mt = testType();
    System.out.println(mt.getClass().toString());
    System.out.println(mt.getClass().getName());

    String type = "acceleration";
    String[] units = new String[8];

    Object mType;
    if(type.equals("acceleration")) {
      mType = new Acceleration();
    } else if(type.equals("density")) {
      mType = new Density();
    } else {
      mType = new Object();
    }

    System.out.println(mType.getName());
  }
}
```

This is where i encountered the problem that I was thinking about. I was using strings to determine the type that I would instantiate, but the problem is, by default right at the end of the conditional statements I instantiate Object because otherwise the compiler would complain that the `mType` variable wouldn't have been initialized. I can't create a `MeasurementType` object since it is an abstract class.

I guess this is more of a design question, but is there a better way of determining the class to instantiate? Please assume that the `String type = "acceleration"` came from a drop down or somewhere from some user interface, I have just hard coded it in because it isn't really necessary for the question.

Could someone shed some light on this design fault as I see it please.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by your first part; you have two identical subclasses but then say you are going to make them unique. At which point it makes sense

Comment: I have to wonder if you are using Strings ("acceleration" and "density") in places where an enum would make much more sense. The enum gives your code improved type safety in that it would be impossible to pass an enum into a method parameter that doesn't match one of the enum items -- or `null` of course.

Comment: This question is more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com, since it's about design style rather than implementation correctness.

Comment: This question is suited for codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this factory-like codes may help. This saves 100 `if equals and new Xxxx()` statements if you have 100 subTypes.

```
public abstract class MeasurementType {
    protected  String name;

    private static final Map<String, Class<? extends MeasurementType>> typeMap = new HashMap<>();
    static{
        typeMap.put("accelaration", Acceleration.class);
        typeMap.put("density", Density.class);
       //put here if you have others
    }

    public static MeasurementType getMeasurement(String keyStr) throws RuntimeException {
        if (typeMap.containsKey(keyStr)) {
            try {
                return typeMap.get(keyStr).newInstance();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("creation failed.");
            }
        }
            //this could be a speical exception type
        throw new RuntimeException("creation failed: unknown type"); 
    }

}
```

in your `run` class/method:

```
        String s = "accelaration";
        String s2 = "trash";
        MeasurementType t = null;

        try {
            t =MeasurementType.getMeasurement(s);
            t = MeasurementType.getMeasurement(s2); //throw ex
        }catch (RuntimeException e){
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: Kind of nitpicking, but `RuntimeException` is as bad as the `catch (Exception)` clause. The throw begs for `IllegalArgumentException`, the catch for a `ClassNotFoundException`. There are enough pokemon-trainers-turned-developers in the world as is.

Comment: Isn't reflection generally considered somewhat scary?

Comment: Here is a good article contrasting the use of reflection against the more conventional approach in the factory pattern, good read IMO: http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Comment: I often use something a little like this, but with a `Provider` interface which provides a new Object on demand and lambdas to make the use of it a little shorter (instead of an annonomous inner class); avoids the reflection and is a little more flexible with differing constructor arguments. cc @SimonKuang

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the crux of your question, what to do when the string is neither "acceleration" or "density".

```
if(type.equals("acceleration")) {
  mType = new Acceleration();
} else if(type.equals("density")) {
  mType = new Density();
} else {
  mType = new Object();
}
```

Is this a sign that something in your program has broken, that it is irretrievable wrong? In which case; throw an exception.

```
if(type.equals("acceleration")) {
  mType = new Acceleration();
} else if(type.equals("density")) {
  mType = new Density();
} else {
  throw new RuntimeException("variable type is not a valid type, valid types are 'acceleration' and 'density'";
}
```

This is a realisation you will come to; exceptions are your friend. They mean when the program is wrong it screams where and why and then you fix it. On the other hand quietly ignoring the problem leads to subtle bugs and strange behaviour that can take days to diagnose.

On the other hand is this a sign of the user entering inappropriate input? In that case, validate the input and if its invalid tell the end user and ask for it again.

Using `String`s and if statements like this is likely not to be what you want to do at all, but under the assumption it is what you want to do then this is the way forward (a switch statement would be slightly nicer).

Answer (score 5):

If the string is not one of the reconized measurement type names, you shouldn't create an Object. You should signal the problem by throwing an exception:

```
public MeasurementType fromString(String type) {
    if (type.equals("acceleration")) {
        return new Acceleration();
    } 
    else if (type.equals("density")) {
        return new Density();
    } 
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(type + " is not a known measurement type");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

one way is to add a `DefaultMesurementType` subclass to MesurementType subclasses. this also known as [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)...

another way to bypass compiler error is to simply assign `null` to `mType` :

```
MesurementType mType = null;
if(type.equals("acceleration")) {
    mType = new Acceleration();
} else if(type.equals("density")) {
    mType = new Density();
}
```

Comment: Lets be honest; I *do* do this, but it is a dangerous game; you can get NullPointerExceptions far from where the problem actually is

Comment: @RichardTingle yes, for that i mentioned Null Object Pattern...

Answer (score 3):

As for your specific issue, your final `else` clause should either return null (IMO ugly) or, preferably, throw an Exception.

```
else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(type + " is not a legal type.");
}
```

Also, be very wary of passing in arrays to a constructor / setter, as the caller still has a reference to it and could modify it.  You probably want to make a defensive copy.

Answer (score 3):

Let's put some shed on design & try to improve it for flexibility & maintainability ...
1) First of all use a design principle **"Program to an interface but not an implementation"** in the following part of your code.

```
public static MeasurementType testType() {
    MeasurementType a = new Acceleration("meters per second");
    return a;
  }
```

2) You can use **Factory Pattern** to get a correct MeasurementType depending upon the **mType** provided by the client.

```
public static MeasurementType testType(String mType) {
        MeasurementType a = MeasurementFactory.getMeasurementType(mType);
        return a;
      }
```

3) Always keep in mind the most important design principle - **"Encapsulate What Varies"**. Now it's time to extract out the part of the code that may change in future. Make a factory...

```
public class MeasurementFactory {

    public static MeasurementType getMeasurementType(String mType) {

        if (mType.equals("acceleration")) {
            return new Acceleration();
        } else if (mType.equals("density")) {
            return new Density();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid MeasurementType");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your design is more flexible & better. Every time you add a new MeasurementType, you need to change the MeasurementFactory class rather than cascading down change everywhere.

Comment: This still has the possibility for a 'null` floating around. I'd much prefer an exception since that causes problems at the site of the mistake not a nullpointerException far from the real problem

Comment: Thanks Richard, I just ignored that while writing code. Generally I return null in the else of Factory & catch the NullPointerException at appropriate place.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're right. It is a design problem. Always bear in mind that different classes should have different behavior, so only make different classes where it makes sense to make them. Also to answer your problem, you might want to take a look at the [strategy design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy). Yours is a classic problem of software and also has a classic answer. Please check it and try to implement it.